# Value was either too large or too small for an Int16 error

Tags: vb.net

I am working on fixing a bug in VB that is giving this error.  I am new to VB, so there is some syntax that I am not fully understanding.  The code that is throwing the error says:

.Row(itemIndex).Item("parentIndex") = CLng(oID) + 1000000

I understand that adding 1000000 is too much for an int16.  I can't change that value (not right now anyway).  What I don't understand, and can't seem to find, is what .Row is referring too.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the `.Row` do you see a `With` keyword?

With allows you to do stuff like this:

```
With myClass
   .FirstName  ="John"
End With
```

Which is the same as this:

```
myClass.FirstName = "John"
```

Usually you will use a `With` block if you have a lot of references to the same object. For example:

```
myClass.FirstName = "John"
myClass.FirstName = "John"
myClass.FirstName = "John"
myClass.FirstName = "John"
myClass.FirstName = "John"
```

can be changed to this:

```
With myClass
  .FirstName = "John" 
  .FirstName = "John"
  .FirstName = "John"
  .FirstName = "John"
  .FirstName = "John"
End With
```

EDIT:

I copied and pasted the above code, hence the repeated use of the property `FirstName`.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to post that it is wrapped in a with.  So that is what .Row refers too then huh.  Good to know.  Now I just need to fix the error message.  Thanks.

Comment: Likely the .Row is connected to a grid, or a DataTable? The first line of the With block will help you with figuring this out.